# Why is direction of train like this for car?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity, relative-motion

This is an image of a train and a car. T is the train moving towards - $x$ axis and C is the car moving towards $+ y$axis.
[image]
So, my teacher made a resultant velocity with $-5\hat i$ and $-20\hat j$.  Then he extended that black line which is resultant velocity. Then, my instructor said that the car sees the motion of train along that black line. I am confused with this since the black line does not even touch the car!
So how is that possible ?

Comment: Is there a reason behind why you think the black line should intersect the car?

Comment: If it intersect , that means the car is looking at train@JustJohan

Comment: That line is the path the train takes relative to the car , not the line of sight.

Comment: This is an interesting question regarding perspective. Might not be intuitive for everyone. As @JustJohan explains, the black line is simply the path of the train as seen from the car if you imagine the car itself as stationary and not moving.   
 Imagine sitting in the car and marking on a map where the train is compared to you at different moments. Those markings will lie on this black line. To begin with the markings are in front of you (the car hasn't passed the tracks yet) and a bit to the side; later the markings are behind you (when the car has passed the tracks) and a bit to the side.

Answer (score 0):

The black line is the position of the car (over time) as viewed from the train (in a coordinate system which moves with the train).